# Ability to do a LIKE on two VarChar parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table that looks like:

```
orderID  Code  SubCode
```

based on codes and subCodes i need to be able to pull all orderIDs.

`Codes` and `SubCodes` are varchar values, and i need to be able to do a "like" on it, because a user can, for example have access to 3%  for `Code` and 45% for the `SubCode`
for for the above example, i would get all orders where the `Code` starts with a 3 and the `SubCode` starts with 45.

I have gotten it working with just the `Code` like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [sp_GetOrders]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@codeList varchar(max), 
@subCodeList varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


declare @tempTable Table
(
SearchCode varchar(max)
)
insert  into @tempTable
select  * from dbo.udf_split(@codeList ) as split --this splits comma delimited list 'm passing in 

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT  orderID  from ordert t1
where
exists(
select 1 from @tempTable tt
where t1.userCode  like tt.SearchOrg
)
END
```

the above works, and if i'm passing in 300% for codeList it correctly returns all orders id that have a code of anything that starts with 300, but how do i now also include SubCode in the mix?

i guess it would be better if i was able to pass code and suborg as 1 parameter, to not lose their relationship to each other, maybe something with a dash like '5%-6%' where 5% would be the code and 6% the suborg.. but i have no idea where to even start with that.

from the back end, it does not matter what format to pass the parameters in, i just need to figure out how to get the SP to work.

Comment: Can you change the parameter type to XML? That maybe cleaner way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLServer2008+ you can passing table-valued parameters to SPs and UDFs.A table-value parameter allows you to pass rows of data to your SPs and UDFs in tabular format. To create a table-valued parameter you must first create a *table type* that defines your table structure.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CodeSubCodeValueType
AS TABLE (Code nvarchar(100) NOT NULL, SubCode nvarchar(100) NOT NULL)
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [sp_GetOrders]
 (@CodeSubCodeValueType dbo.CodeSubCodeValueType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN    
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT orderID
  FROM ordert t1
  WHERE EXISTS(
               SELECT 1 
               FROM @CodeSubCodeValueType tt               
               WHERE t1.userCode LIKE tt.Code
                 AND t1.userSubCode LIKE tt.SubCode
               )
END
GO
```

Calling a procedure with a Table-Valued Parameter

```
DECLARE @CodeSubCodeValueType dbo.CodeSubCodeValueType

INSERT @CodeSubCodeValueType
VALUES('5%', '6%'), 
      ('7%', '8%')

EXEC [sp_GetOrders] @CodeSubCodeValueType
```

If one of value of parameters couples is empty, then NULL value is necessary to using in table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CodeSubCodeValueType
AS TABLE (Code nvarchar(100), SubCode nvarchar(100))
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [sp_GetOrders]
 (@CodeSubCodeValueType dbo.CodeSubCodeValueType READONLY)
AS
BEGIN    
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT orderID
  FROM ordert t1
  WHERE EXISTS(
               SELECT 1 
               FROM @CodeSubCodeValueType tt               
               WHERE t1.Code LIKE ISNULL(tt.Code, t1.Code)
                 AND t1.SubCode LIKE ISNULL(tt.SubCode, t1.SubCode)
               )
END
GO
```

Simple demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a1d2/1)

Comment: This is way better than the xml option, but I wonder if the subcode should allow nulls (and in that case match to all sub codes)?

Comment: Thanks @Joel Coehoorn for a feedback. If one of value of parameters couples is empty, then NULL value is necessary to using in table type(both columns allow NULL values). Therefore the body of procedure shall be changed(search condition of WHERE clause).

Answer (score 1):

You may consider change input parameter type to `XML`

XML format

```
DECLARE @inputXML AS XML = 
 '<ParameterList>
    <Parameter>
        <Code>300%</Code>
        <SubCode>5%</SubCode>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
        <Code>10%</Code>
        <SubCode>6%</SubCode>
    </Parameter>
</ParameterList>'
```

Your stored procedure will be something like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [sp_GetOrders]
    @inputXML XML 
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
(
SearchCode VARCHAR(100),
SearchSubCode VARCHAR(100)
)


INSERT  INTO @tempTable
SELECT
   Pars.value('(Code)[1]', 'Varchar(100)') AS Code,
   Pars.value('(SubCode)[1]', 'Varchar(100)') AS SubCode
FROM
   @inputXML.nodes('/ParameterList/Parameter') AS List(Pars)


SELECT  orderID  
FROM ordert t1
WHERE
EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM @tempTable tt
    WHERE t1.userCode  LIKE tt.SearchCode
    AND t1.userSubCode LIKE tt.SearchSubCode
)
```